# Integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{(1-x^{2})}}{1+x^{2}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Consider $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{(1-x^{2})}}{1+x^{2}}dx$$ I have a problem with this integral; the method I know consists in calculating the complex integral of $$f(z) = \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1+z}{1+z^{2}}$$ along the curve formed by the " shrinking dogbone contour" withe centres $\{-1,1\}$ and the circumference of radius $R \rightarrow \infty$. But I obtain $0$, impossible. What's wrong with this method ?

In particular, what are the residues of $f(z) $ in $\{-i,i\} ? $

Comment: More details about your calculations?

Comment: I have edited, what are the residues of $f(z)$ in $\{ -i , i\}$ ?

Comment: The dogbone is supposed to go around the residues. Here the residues are $\pm\mathrm i$.

Comment: @RonGordon: Do you know how to solve this integral with my method ?

Comment: @WLOG: yes, I do.

Comment: @RonGordon: Can you answer ? Or should I repost the question ?

Comment: @WLOG: actually, RandomVariable has answered most of the question.  And I just realized that I did TedShifrin a disservice and ignored achillehui's comment.  The combination of these answers should get you what you need.  So, no, do not bother reposting.

Comment: @RonGordon: ok, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited answer**

If you need to use the residue method, you should try the following change of variable : $x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ which will allow you to write $I$ as an integral of a rational function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. You will be able to use the method you know by using a contour a circumference of radius $R\to\infty$.

*Note*: In my previous answer, I doubted the pertinence of residues, a statement that has been denied by @RonGordon.

Comment: @RonGordon. Although I have a long practice of integrals, I do not pretend that I know everything. I am here to learn and would very much appreciate if you could share your knowledge.

Comment: See the duplicate answer.